# How to access a in-memory database in spring

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a standalone java application using in-memory embedded database. I refereed few documents and I wrote the following code. I am using spring Boot.
 These are the steps I did so far:
In, pom file I added these dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
             <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

In application.properties file

```
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

I created a scripts  schema.sql and data.sql
schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

data.sql

```
insert into users(id, name, email) values(1,'demouser','user@test.com');
```

Here is my repository class.

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from users", new UserRowMapper());
    }

    class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            return user;
        }
```

Here is my junit class

```
@Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addDefaultScripts().build();
        Object db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("schema.sql")
                .addScript("data.sql").build();
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println(users.get(0).getName());
        assertNotNull(users);
        assertTrue(!users.isEmpty());
    }
```

when I run  my junit I am getting the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Do I have to add any other dependency or download a database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use In-memory database which is H2 so you shouldn't be having MySql dependecy in pom.xml and mysql related properties in `application.properties`.

Remove the MySql connector dependency from `pom.xml`

```
    <!--Delete This-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.36</version>
```

And delete all the properties in `application.properties` file.
Keep it blank, Spring boot will auto-configure these properties for H2 database.

Checkout the complete [Spring Boot JDBC Demo](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/SpringBootJDBCDemo) project in the GitHub repository.

Comment: @madhu please accept it if this answers your question.